# Can't edit Custom Post Type slug/permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

I have a custom post type and the permalink shows up but I am unable to modify it like I can with Pages and Posts. Is there a way to enable this? I have a few conflicts with some pages and I'd like to fix them but I can't. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a tab in wp-admin for your cpt?

Comment: Why do you have conflicts? This is unlikely unless you bent permalinks in some non-default direction, which very well might be the reason for issue with editing.

Comment: Clients aren't always conscious of these things when created content. They created the CPT post first, but it's not meant to have a page. So when they created a page, they named it the same thing. Got the -2 after the slug. Don't want that if we can avoid it.

Comment: duplicate slugs shouldn't be an issue in different post types. are there posts in the trash with the same slug?

Comment: Nope wasn't anything in the trash. As soon as I changed it via the database thought I was able to change the Page. So something was linked. I found under Screen Options a box for Slug. It didn't quite work the same as on Pages but it gave a box for editing it. Did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a box under Screen Options to display the Slug on the custom post type. Created a metabox with the slug to be edited, not quite how it works on Pages but it solved the issue.